# Matlab basic matrix transformation to vector

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector

I have a matrix like this: data(:,61:90)
I would like to make a vector from this where columns 61...90 are appended vertically.
What is the best way to do this?

Comment: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html

Comment: Oli Charlesworth pointed me in the right direction, I solved it using reshape( data(:,61:90) , [], 1 )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `reshape()` to reshape array and `vec2mat()` to convert vector to matrix.
Try this code for your problem.

```
my_vect = data(:,61:90);
my_vect = reshape(my_vect,[],1);
```

or simply:

```
my_vect = my_vect(:);
```